# Thread exception when using Messages

Tags: c#, multithreading, mvvm, notifications, message

In Windows Phone application in my constructor of the ViewModel I register a messenger like this:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<MyType>
(
    this,
    (action) => ReceiveMessage(action)
);
```

Then in the ReceiveMessage I try to put some code and it crashes with

```
"The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread."

private void ReceiveMessage(MyType action)
{
    this.MyCollection.Clear();

    foreach (Student st in Students)
    {
        this.MyCollection.Add(st);
    }
}
```

I tried doing this and it comes with the same result:

```
Application.Current.Resources.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => this.MyCollection.Clear());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the call to `Dispatcher.RunAsync()` in your registered handler, so that the entire call to `ReceiveMessage()` is invoked, not just one statement of that method.

```
Messenger.Default.Register<MyType>
(
    this,
    (action) => Application.Current.Resources.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
        CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => ReceiveMessage(action))
);
```

Of course, change your `ReceiveMessage()` method back to the way it was originally (without the dispatcher-invoke).

Also, I'm not convinced the Dispatcher from the Resources is the right one; it's certainly not how I've done it in WinRT. Maybe that's a Phone thing, but if the above still doesn't work, try using `Application.Current.Dispatcher` instead.

Comment: What is the stack trace? What thread are you using when you call the `Register<T>()` method? Did you try `Application.Current.Dispatcher`? Or is that not available in the `Application` class for Phone?